# RemoveChild does not work despite there is no error

Tags: javascript, logic, removechild

```js
var disP = document.getElementById("display");
var num = 0;
document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click",function(){
    num++;
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
    newDiv.id = "newDiv" + num;
    newDiv.style.width = 100 + "px";
    newDiv.style.height = 100 + "px";
    newDiv.style.position= "relative";
    newDiv.style.display = "inline-block";
    disP.appendChild(newDiv);
    

});

disP.addEventListener("click",function(){
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    disP.appendChild(newDiv);
    disP.removeChild(newDiv);
    
});
```

```css
#ctrl2 #plus {
    background-color:rgb(128,128,128);
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">
</div>

<div id="ctrl2">
   <button id="plus" value="+" type="button">+</button> <span>|</span>
</div>

<div id=display></div>
```

Hi, I am trying to create a function where I can delete any of the individual div(box) regardless the order by clicking the div(box). I get no errors but nothing is happening. I would appreciate any tips and help!

P.S We were told in school to use "RemoveChild()" to get this work without relying on other methods but I am open to other options as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `disP` listener an argument for the event, so you can identify the event's target (the clicked square), so you can remove the clicked square:

```js
var disP = document.getElementById("display");
var num = 0;
document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click",function(){
    num++;
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    var g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    var b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
    newDiv.id = "newDiv" + num;
    newDiv.style.width = 100 + "px";
    newDiv.style.height = 100 + "px";
    newDiv.style.position= "relative";
    newDiv.style.display = "inline-block";
    disP.appendChild(newDiv);
});

disP.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target !== disP) e.target.remove();
});
```

```css
#ctrl2 #plus {
    background-color:rgb(128,128,128);
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">
</div>

<div id="ctrl2">
   <button id="plus" value="+" type="button">+</button> <span>|</span>
</div>

<div id=display></div>
```

(`.remove()` is a bit less verbose than `.removeChild` and achieves the same thing)

Comment: Thank you so much for solving the problem. Could you elaborate "e => {
  if (e.target !== disP)" part? I do not understand why there is an if statement along with => and !== operator. Does the "e" stand for event?

Comment: It checks to see if the clicked element (the `e.target`) is `disp` or whether it's one of the colored squares. If it's the `disp`, then you don't want to remove it from the document, of course. `e` is just an argument, it can be whatever (valid variable) string you want.